# Blacklisting pcspkr module doesn't work on CentOS 5.7

Tags: linux, terminal, centos

I hate the terminal beep and I want it removed completely. I added this line to my /etc/modproble.d/blacklist.conf file:

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

However when I reboot the lsmod output shows it loaded:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsmod | grep pcspkr
pcspkr                  7105  0
```

I'm running CentOS 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put something like this...

> rmmod pcspkr

...in some of the startup scripts (such as /etc/init.d/rc.local)

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to create a conf file for pcspkr (as root):

```
echo "blacklist pcspkr" >> /etc/modprobe.d/pcspkr.conf
```

That will stop the module from being loaded next time you reboot. You will still have to run

```
rmmod pcspkr
```

to unload the module from the already running system.

Comment: The pcspkr module is still in lsmod output after trying your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of problem with the nouveau module on Fedora 16. It seems to be caused by the presence of the module in the init ramdisk. You can try to make a new one (after you've added the blacklist line in modprode.d).

Try to do this :

```
cd /boot
mv initrd-$(uname -r).img initrd-$(uname -r).pcspkr.img
mkinitrd initrd-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```

See [this CentOS wiki entry](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CreateNewInitrd?highlight=%28initrd%29)

Answer (score 1):

A more permanent (and OS-independent) solution is to open the PC case and disconnect the internal speaker from the motherboard.

It is a 4-pin connector with only two wires that looks like this:

[image]

You will find it connected somewhere near the edge of the motherboard along with several other connectors, looking similar to this:

[image]